# What evidence is there that bottom and top quarks come in 3 colors?

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, quarks

We know, because of baryons such as the triple-strange [Omega baryon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_baryon) spin 3/2, that at least the quarks 'up', 'down', and 'strange' must come in 3 colors because of the Pauli exclusion principle.

No triple baryons of ccc, bbb or ttt have (so far) been observed. Thus (I would say) there is no reason (as yet) to suppose that they also must come in 3 colors.

One might say that QCD works for these heavy quarks too. But, since there are so few baryons and mesons made of these heavy quarks, one really has a free parameter (the mass) to play with so it is less predictive.

Therefor, it is concievable and possible that the top and bottom quarks may come in a smaller number of colors or none at all. e.g. the top quark could only come in red/anti-red, the bottom quark might only come in green/anti-green. So no ttt baryons could exist. top/anti-top mesons could still exist held together by neutral gluon currents. Alternatively the top and bottom quarks could come in more colors.

So other than appealing to beauty and symmetry, is there any phsyical evidence that top and bottom quarks come in 3 colors? Is it conceivable that we have added too many particles to the standard model?

Is there someway to prove that top and bottom mesons must be held together with SU(3) forces?

Comment: Isn't the statement that there aren't any Top quark based particles more a statement of the fact that they decay long before  any useful composite particles can be made of them?

Comment: Does this help regarding the number of distinct colour charges? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(cross_section_ratio)

Comment: @Triatticus. Yes, that would be one expanation. The other explanation would be that they can't exist. We have no way of knowing which is true yet, I contend.

Comment: @Charlie. Perhaps, but does that involve the mass ratios? In which case it can't prove it since we have no way of getting the bare masses of the quarks. The masses depend on which model we use.